# Trouble with a small library-management program

Tags: java

I'm having major trouble piecing this together. I have basic read and write functionality. What I need is for the input from file 'Books.txt' to be checked so that:

- ISBN is valid
- CopyNumber, Year and Statistics should be numeric
- Title, Author and Publisher must contain values
- BorrowDate must be a valid date
- ReturnDate if available must be a valid date
- LibraryCardNumber if available must be numeric.

If a book is not borrowed the two last fields are nonexistent.

2 sample rows from 'Books.txt':

```
9780140455168#2#The Twelve Caesars#Suetonius#Penguin Classics#2007#3#101009#101030#5478
9780141188607#1#Claudius the God#Robert Graves#Penguin Classics#2006#2#080123
```

Error lines should be written to 'ErrorLines.txt' with an error-message, e.g. Wrong ISBN. Error-free books should be written to 'NewBooks.txt' sorted by name of author.

Here's what I've got so far. I'm not looking for a complete solution, because I obviously have a looong way to go, but if someone would be so kind as to give me some pointers, I'd be extremely grateful! And yes, it's homework :D

Do I need to make a try loop to validate the input...?

The Library class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Library {

public void readFromFile (String filename) throws IOException {

String inLine;
File inFile;

    inFile = new File("Books.txt");
    BufferedReader fIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));

        inLine = fIn.readLine();
        while (inLine != null) {
            inLine = fIn.readLine();
            aBookList.add(inLine + "\n");
        }
        fIn.close();
    }

public void writeToFile (String fileName) throws IOException {

    BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));

            bw.write("???"); //Dont know what to put here...
            bw.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error writing file.");
        } finally {
            bw.close();
        }
    }

 public static boolean isISBN13Valid(isbn) {
        int check = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i += 2) {
            check += Integer.valueOf(isbn.substring(i, i + 1));
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 12; i += 2) {
            check += Integer.valueOf(isbn.substring(i, i + 1)) * 3;
        }
        check += Integer.valueOf(isbn.substring(12));
        return check % 10 == 0;
    }
}
```

And here's the Book class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Book {
Book b = new Book();
private static ArrayList<String> aBookList = new ArrayList<String>();

private String Isbn;
private int CopyNumber;
private String Title;
private String Author;
private String Publisher;
private int Year;
private int Statistics;
private String BorrowDate;
private String ReturnDate;
private int LibraryCardNumber;

public void bookInfo (String nIsbn, int nCopyNumber, String nTitle, String nAuthor, String nPublisher, int nYear,
        int nStatistics, String nBorrowDate, String nReturnDate, int nLibraryCardNumber) {

    Isbn = nIsbn; 
    CopyNumber = nCopyNumber; 
    Title = nTitle; 
    Author = nAuthor; 
    Publisher = nPublisher; 
    Year = nYear;
    Statistics = nStatistics; 
    BorrowDate = nBorrowDate; 
    ReturnDate = nReturnDate; 
    LibraryCardNumber = nLibraryCardNumber;
}

public void bookInfo (String Row) {
    StringTokenizer sT = new StringTokenizer(Row);
    Isbn = sT.nextToken("#");
    CopyNumber = Integer.parseInt(sT.nextToken("#") );
    Title = sT.nextToken("#");
    Author = sT.nextToken("#");
    Publisher = sT.nextToken("#");
    Year = Integer.parseInt(sT.nextToken("#") );
    Statistics = Integer.parseInt(sT.nextToken("#") );
    BorrowDate = sT.nextToken("#");
    ReturnDate = sT.nextToken("#");
    LibraryCardNumber = Integer.parseInt(sT.nextToken("#") );
}
public void setIsbn(String nIsbn) {
    Isbn = nIsbn;       
}
public void setCopynumber(int nCopyNumber) {
    CopyNumber = nCopyNumber;       
}
public void setTitle(String nTitle) {
    Title = nTitle;     
}
public void setAuthor(String nAuthor) {
    Author = nAuthor;       
}
public void setPublisher(String nPublisher) {
    Publisher = nPublisher;     
}
public void setYear(int nYear) {
    Year = nYear;       
}
public void setStatistics(int nStatistics) {
    Statistics = nStatistics;       
}
public void setBorrowDate(String nBorrowDate) {
    BorrowDate = nBorrowDate;       
}
public void setReturnDate(String nReturnDate) {
    ReturnDate = nReturnDate;
}
public void setLibraryCardNumber(int nLibraryCardNumber) {
    LibraryCardNumber = nLibraryCardNumber;
}

 public String getAll () {
    String s = " ";
    return (Isbn + s + CopyNumber + s + Title + s + Author + s + Publisher + s +
                   Year + s + Statistics + s + BorrowDate + s + ReturnDate + s +
                   LibraryCardNumber);
}
public void showAll () {
    String t = "\t";
    System.out.println(Isbn + t + CopyNumber + t + Title + t + Author + t +
                       Publisher + t + Year + t + Statistics + t + 
                       BorrowDate + t + ReturnDate + t + LibraryCardNumber);
}
}
```

And finally there's the Main class with main method:

```
public class Main<aBookList> implements Comparable<aBookList> {
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {

    new Library().readFromFile("Books.txt");

    new Library().writeToFile("NewBooks.txt");
    new Library().writeToFile("ErrorLines.txt");

}

@Override
public int compareTo(aBookList o) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as it is homework, i will point you direction, not give you code

1) you have lot of mess here, ie i'm not sure why you have compare in your main class? instead of creating getAll method in bookInfo(which is named against java nameing convention) just override toString method

2) why do you have list of strings? read a line, convert this into book, if book is valid add it to your list, otherwise report an error

3) move your isISBN13Valid method to book

4) write to file -> loop through your list, and save each element into file by   `bw.write(book.toString())`,

5) create second method createErrorFile, then each error what you will have add into your error list, and after you call that method, you will sace each element into given file, it is not perfetc solution, better will  be if you add error to file each time when it occur.

6) create one instance of library in your main method, and just call on it all your method, and avoid using static fields in your project(sometimes you must, but if you don;t need, just avoid them)

7) names for method import/ export i think sounds nicer than read from file read from file